# Issue With cache Abstraction using redis

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis, spring-data

I have a Problem with Spring - Data - Redis
I am using redis as cache for entities that i am fetching from database using JPA Repository.
Here is the entity structure :

```
@Entity(name = "issue_category")
public class IssueCategory extends AuditablePersistable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8659360844089652714L;
private Integer parentId;
private String name;
private String displayNameCRM;
private String displayNameSelfServe;
private List<IssueCategoryRule> issueCategoryRules = new ArrayList<>();

public static final Integer ROOT_PARENT_ID = 0;
```

// with all getter setters
}

Here is  part where i am caching it:

```
 @Override
@Cacheable(value = IC_CACHE, key = "#id")
public IssueCategory getIssueCategoriesById(Integer id) {
    return issueCategoriesRepo.findById(id);
}
```

The Repo code for getting from db:

```
public interface IssueCategoryRepo extends JpaRepository<IssueCategory, Integer>  
    {
     public IssueCategory findByName(@Param("name") String name);
     public List<IssueCategory> findByParentId(@Param("parentId") Integer parentId);
     public IssueCategory findById(@Param("id") Integer id);
    }
```

The problem I am getting is
Class Cast exception when this entity is being extracted from cache
It says :

> Can not cast from java.util.ArrayList to IssueCategory class.

Can anybody help.